# Сравнение результата, полученного с QLineEdit, с данным

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, sqlite3, qt-designer

Даже при том, что я вызываю метод `lineEdit.text()`, строка из поля ввода не берётся, поэтому в конце выдаётся неверный ответ.

Также при нажатии кнопки "**`Закрыть`**" вылезает ошибка:

> Process finished with exit code 1073741845.

Заранее благодарен за решение проблемы.

```
import sqlite3
import sys
from random import choice

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow

con = sqlite3.connect('project_pyqt.db')
cur = con.cursor()

sk4 = 0
sk_rv4 = 0
list_nt4 = []
for i in cur.execute('select id_t4 from task_4').fetchall():
    list_nt4.append(*i)


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(816, 460)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(816, 460))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(816, 460))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setGeometry(
            QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 801, 441))
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setObjectName("gridLayoutWidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.task_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        self.task_4.setFont(font)
        self.task_4.setObjectName("task_4")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.task_4)
        self.task_7 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        self.task_7.setFont(font)
        self.task_7.setObjectName("task_7")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.task_7)
        self.task_9 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        self.task_9.setFont(font)
        self.task_9.setObjectName("task_9")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.task_9)
        self.horizontalLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout)
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.task_10 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        self.task_10.setFont(font)
        self.task_10.setObjectName("task_10")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.task_10)
        self.task_11 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        self.task_11.setFont(font)
        self.task_11.setObjectName("task_11")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.task_11)
        self.task_12 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        self.task_12.setFont(font)
        self.task_12.setObjectName("task_12")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.task_12)
        self.horizontalLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_2)
        self.verticalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_3.setObjectName("verticalLayout_3")
        self.task_13 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        self.task_13.setFont(font)
        self.task_13.setObjectName("task_13")
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.task_13)
        self.task_14 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        self.task_14.setFont(font)
        self.task_14.setObjectName("task_14")
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.task_14)
        self.task_15 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        self.task_15.setFont(font)
        self.task_15.setObjectName("task_15")
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.task_15)
        self.horizontalLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_3)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.title_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(26)
        self.title_label.setFont(font)
        self.title_label.setObjectName("title_label")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.title_label, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(
            _translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.task_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Задание №4"))
        self.task_7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Задание №7"))
        self.task_9.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Задание №9"))
        self.task_10.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Задание №10"))
        self.task_11.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Задание №11"))
        self.task_12.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Задание №12"))
        self.task_13.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Задание №13"))
        self.task_14.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Задание №14"))
        self.task_15.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Задание №15"))
        self.title_label.setText(_translate("MainWindow",
                                            "Тренажёр для подготовки к ЕГЭ по русскому языку"))


class Ui_MainWindow4(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 445)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 10, 696, 95))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.label_4.setFont(font)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.outlabel_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.outlabel_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 340, 91, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.outlabel_4.setFont(font)
        self.outlabel_4.setObjectName("outlabel_4")
        self.n_btn_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.n_btn_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(560, 390, 198, 39))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.n_btn_4.setFont(font)
        self.n_btn_4.setObjectName("n_btn_4")
        self.verticalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(
            self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(
            QtCore.QRect(20, 120, 191, 201))
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setObjectName(
            "verticalLayoutWidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(
            self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.label_41 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.label_41.setFont(font)
        self.label_41.setObjectName("label_41")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label_41)
        self.label_42 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.label_42.setFont(font)
        self.label_42.setObjectName("label_42")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label_42)
        self.label_43 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.label_43.setFont(font)
        self.label_43.setObjectName("label_43")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label_43)
        self.label_44 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.label_44.setFont(font)
        self.label_44.setObjectName("label_44")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label_44)
        self.label_45 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.label_45.setFont(font)
        self.label_45.setObjectName("label_45")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label_45)
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 340, 651, 31))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(
            _translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow",
                                        ""))
        self.outlabel_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ответ:"))
        self.n_btn_4.setText(
            _translate("MainWindow", "Отправить ответ"))
        self.label_41.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1 слово"))
        self.label_42.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "2 слово"))
        self.label_43.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "3 слово"))
        self.label_44.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "4 слово"))
        self.label_45.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "5 слово"))


class ForthTask(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow4):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle('Задание №4')
        self.test_t4()
        self.n_btn_4.clicked.connect(self.check_rv4)

    def test_t4(self):
        global sk4, sk_rv4, list_nt4
        sk4 += 1
        self.id4 = choice(list_nt4)
        list_nt4.remove(self.id4)
        if sk4 % 10 != 0:
            self.st_t4()
        else:
            self.resuit_w = Res()
            self.resuit_w.show()
            self.hide()

    def check_rv4(self):
        global sk_rv4
        self.st_t4()
        self.rv = cur.execute(
            f'''select right_var_4 from 
            task_4 where id_t4 = {self.id4}''').fetchall()
        print(self.lineEdit.text())
        print(self.rv[0][0])
        if self.lineEdit.text() == self.rv[0][0]:
            sk_rv4 += 1
        self.test_t4()

    def st_t4(self):
        self.task = cur.execute(
            f'''select task_4 from task_4 
            where id_t4 = {self.id4}''').fetchall()
        self.var1 = cur.execute(
            f'''select var_41 from task_4
            where id_t4 = {self.id4}''').fetchall()
        self.var2 = cur.execute(
            f'''select var_42 from task_4
                    where id_t4 = {self.id4}''').fetchall()
        self.var3 = cur.execute(
            f'''select var_43 from task_4
                    where id_t4 = {self.id4}''').fetchall()
        self.var4 = cur.execute(
            f'''select var_44 from task_4
                    where id_t4 = {self.id4}''').fetchall()
        self.var5 = cur.execute(
            f'''select var_45 from task_4
                    where id_t4 = {self.id4}''').fetchall()
        self.label_4.setText(self.task[0][0])
        self.label_41.setText(self.var1[0][0])
        self.label_42.setText(self.var2[0][0])
        self.label_43.setText(self.var3[0][0])
        self.label_44.setText(self.var4[0][0])
        self.label_45.setText(self.var5[0][0])
        self.label_4.resize(self.label_4.sizeHint())
        self.lineEdit.setText('')


class Ui_MainWindowres(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(391, 143)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(391, 143))
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(
            self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(
            QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 373, 129))
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setObjectName(
            "verticalLayoutWidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(
            self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.r_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.r_label.setFont(font)
        self.r_label.setObjectName("r_label")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.r_label)
        self.res_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.res_label.setFont(font)
        self.res_label.setObjectName("res_label")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.res_label)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)
        self.help = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.help.setFont(font)
        self.help.setObjectName("help")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.help)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(
            self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(
            _translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.r_label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Результат:"))
        self.res_label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ваываыа"))
        self.help.setText(_translate("MainWindow",
                                     "Для того, чтобы завершить тестирование по \n"
                                     "данному заданию, нажмите кнопку \"Закрыть\""))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Закрыть"))


class Res(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindowres):
    def __init__(self):
        global sk_rv4, sk4
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle('Результат')
        self.res_label.setText(f'{sk_rv4} / {sk4}')
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.close)

    def close(self):
        self.close()
        ex.show()


class Application(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle(
            'Тренажёр для подготовки к ЕГЭ по русскому языку')

        self.task_4.clicked.connect(self.forth_task)

    def forth_task(self):
        self.hide()
        self.window_4 = ForthTask()
        self.window_4.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Application()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Скрипт формирования таблицы, откуда беруться данные:

```
CREATE TABLE task_4 (id_t4 int, task_4 text, right_var_4 text, var_41 TEXT, var_42 TEXT, var_43 TEXT, var_44 TEXT, var_45 TEXT, PRIMARY KEY (id_t4));
INSERT INTO task_4 (id_t4, task_4, right_var_4, var_41, var_42, var_43, var_44, var_45) VALUES (1, 'В одном из приведённых ниже слов допущена ошибка в 
постановке ударения: НЕВЕРНО выделена буква, 
обозначающая ударный гласный звук. Выпишите это слово.', 'отзыв', 'созЫв', 'Отзыв (посла)', 'добелА', 'оптОвый', 'тубдиспансЕр');
INSERT INTO task_4 (id_t4, task_4, right_var_4, var_41, var_42, var_43, var_44, var_45) VALUES (2, 'В одном из приведённых ниже слов допущена ошибка в 
постановке ударения: НЕВЕРНО выделена буква, 
обозначающая ударный гласный звук. Выпишите это слово.', 'аэропорты', 'создАвший', 'каталОг', 'начАв', 'тОрты', 'аэропортЫ');
INSERT INTO task_4 (id_t4, task_4, right_var_4, var_41, var_42, var_43, var_44, var_45) VALUES (3, 'В одном из приведённых ниже слов допущена ошибка в 
постановке ударения: НЕВЕРНО выделена буква, 
обозначающая ударный гласный звук. Выпишите это слово.', 'поняла', 'обострЁнный', 'бАнты', 'начАть', 'досУг', 'пОняла');
INSERT INTO task_4 (id_t4, task_4, right_var_4, var_41, var_42, var_43, var_44, var_45) VALUES (4, 'В одном из приведённых ниже слов допущена ошибка в 
постановке ударения: НЕВЕРНО выделена буква, 
обозначающая ударный гласный звук. Выпишите это слово.', 'сливовый', 'укрАла', 'клАла', 'звонИт', 'прИняли', 'сливОвый (сок)');
INSERT INTO task_4 (id_t4, task_4, right_var_4, var_41, var_42, var_43, var_44, var_45) VALUES (5, 'В одном из приведённых ниже слов допущена ошибка в 
постановке ударения: НЕВЕРНО выделена буква, 
обозначающая ударный гласный звук. Выпишите это слово.', 'новостей', 'квартАл', 'мЕстностей', 'ободрИть', 'принУдить', 'нОвостей');
INSERT INTO task_4 (id_t4, task_4, right_var_4, var_41, var_42, var_43, var_44, var_45) VALUES (6, 'В одном из приведённых ниже слов допущена ошибка в 
постановке ударения: НЕВЕРНО выделена буква, 
обозначающая ударный гласный звук. Выпишите это слово.', 'произведен', 'произвЕден', 'зАгодя', 'некролОг', 'облилАсь', 'началА');
INSERT INTO task_4 (id_t4, task_4, right_var_4, var_41, var_42, var_43, var_44, var_45) VALUES (7, 'В одном из приведённых ниже слов допущена ошибка в 
постановке ударения: НЕВЕРНО выделена буква, 
обозначающая ударный гласный звук. Выпишите это слово.', 'включит', 'убыстрИть', 'позвонИм', 'опОшлить', 'вручИт', 'вклЮчит');
INSERT INTO task_4 (id_t4, task_4, right_var_4, var_41, var_42, var_43, var_44, var_45) VALUES (8, 'В одном из приведённых ниже слов допущена ошибка в 
постановке ударения: НЕВЕРНО выделена буква, 
обозначающая ударный гласный звук. Выпишите это слово.', 'цепочка', 'вручАт', 'клАла', 'цЕпочка', 'завИдно', 'чЕрпать');
INSERT INTO task_4 (id_t4, task_4, right_var_4, var_41, var_42, var_43, var_44, var_45) VALUES (9, 'В одном из приведённых ниже слов допущена ошибка в 
постановке ударения: НЕВЕРНО выделена буква, 
обозначающая ударный гласный звук. Выпишите это слово.', 'эксперт', 'клАла', 'взялА', 'Эксперт', 'бралА', 'квартАл');
INSERT INTO task_4 (id_t4, task_4, right_var_4, var_41, var_42, var_43, var_44, var_45) VALUES (10, 'В одном из приведённых ниже слов допущена ошибка в 
постановке ударения: НЕВЕРНО выделена буква, 
обозначающая ударный гласный звук. Выпишите это слово.', 'сливовый', 'Иконопись', 'сливОвый', 'пОгнутый', 'грУшевый', 'кровоточИть');
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]. Где модули `res_des.py` и `task_4.py` ? А также предоставьте скрипт, который сформирует `project_pyqt.db` с данными.

Comment: Да, не продумал этот момент. Прошу простить.

Comment: Правил свой вопрос, добавив необходимые данные

Comment: я посмотрю ваш вопрос, не беспокойтесь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Из-за этого у вас не получалось. Это надо делать в другом месте.

   ```
    self.lineEdit.setText('')
   ```
2. Будьте осторожны с именами объектов. Так не правильно

   ```
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.close)       
    ...
    def close(self): 
        ...
   ```
3. и др.

Старайтесь не использовать глобальные переменные.

**main.py**

```
import sqlite3
import sys
from random import choice

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(816, 460)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(816, 460))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(816, 460))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setGeometry(
            QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 801, 441))
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setObjectName("gridLayoutWidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.task_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        self.task_4.setFont(font)
        self.task_4.setObjectName("task_4")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.task_4)
        self.task_7 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        self.task_7.setFont(font)
        self.task_7.setObjectName("task_7")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.task_7)
        self.task_9 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        self.task_9.setFont(font)
        self.task_9.setObjectName("task_9")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.task_9)
        self.horizontalLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout)
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.task_10 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        self.task_10.setFont(font)
        self.task_10.setObjectName("task_10")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.task_10)
        self.task_11 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        self.task_11.setFont(font)
        self.task_11.setObjectName("task_11")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.task_11)
        self.task_12 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        self.task_12.setFont(font)
        self.task_12.setObjectName("task_12")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.task_12)
        self.horizontalLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_2)
        self.verticalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_3.setObjectName("verticalLayout_3")
        self.task_13 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        self.task_13.setFont(font)
        self.task_13.setObjectName("task_13")
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.task_13)
        self.task_14 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        self.task_14.setFont(font)
        self.task_14.setObjectName("task_14")
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.task_14)
        self.task_15 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        self.task_15.setFont(font)
        self.task_15.setObjectName("task_15")
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.task_15)
        self.horizontalLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_3)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.title_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(26)
        self.title_label.setFont(font)
        self.title_label.setObjectName("title_label")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.title_label, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(
            _translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.task_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Задание №4"))
        self.task_7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Задание №7"))
        self.task_9.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Задание №9"))
        self.task_10.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Задание №10"))
        self.task_11.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Задание №11"))
        self.task_12.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Задание №12"))
        self.task_13.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Задание №13"))
        self.task_14.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Задание №14"))
        self.task_15.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Задание №15"))
        self.title_label.setText(_translate("MainWindow",
                                            "Тренажёр для подготовки к ЕГЭ по русскому языку"))


class Ui_MainWindow4(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 445)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 10, 696, 95))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.label_4.setFont(font)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.outlabel_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.outlabel_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 340, 91, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.outlabel_4.setFont(font)
        self.outlabel_4.setObjectName("outlabel_4")
        self.n_btn_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.n_btn_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(560, 390, 198, 39))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.n_btn_4.setFont(font)
        self.n_btn_4.setObjectName("n_btn_4")
        self.verticalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(
            self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(
            QtCore.QRect(20, 120, 191, 201))
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setObjectName(
            "verticalLayoutWidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(
            self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.label_41 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.label_41.setFont(font)
        self.label_41.setObjectName("label_41")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label_41)
        self.label_42 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.label_42.setFont(font)
        self.label_42.setObjectName("label_42")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label_42)
        self.label_43 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.label_43.setFont(font)
        self.label_43.setObjectName("label_43")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label_43)
        self.label_44 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.label_44.setFont(font)
        self.label_44.setObjectName("label_44")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label_44)
        self.label_45 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.label_45.setFont(font)
        self.label_45.setObjectName("label_45")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label_45)
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 340, 651, 31))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(
            _translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow",
                                        "label_4"))
        self.outlabel_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ответ:"))
        self.n_btn_4.setText(
            _translate("MainWindow", "Отправить ответ"))
        self.label_41.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1 слово"))
        self.label_42.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "2 слово"))
        self.label_43.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "3 слово"))
        self.label_44.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "4 слово"))
        self.label_45.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "5 слово"))


class Ui_MainWindowres(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(391, 143)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(391, 143))
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(
            self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(
            QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 373, 129))
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setObjectName(
            "verticalLayoutWidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(
            self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.r_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.r_label.setFont(font)
        self.r_label.setObjectName("r_label")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.r_label)
        self.res_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.res_label.setFont(font)
        self.res_label.setObjectName("res_label")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.res_label)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)
        self.help = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.help.setFont(font)
        self.help.setObjectName("help")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.help)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(
            self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(
            _translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.r_label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Результат:"))
        self.res_label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ваываыа"))
        self.help.setText(_translate("MainWindow",
                                     "Для того, чтобы завершить тестирование по \n"
                                     "данному заданию, нажмите кнопку \"Закрыть\""))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Закрыть"))


class Res(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindowres):
    def __init__(self):
        global sk_rv4, sk4
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle('Результат')
        self.res_label.setText(f'{sk_rv4} / {sk4}')
# !!!
#        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.close)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.func_close)     # !!! func_close

#   def close(self):                                         # НЕТ
    def func_close(self):                                    # !!! func_close
        self.close()
        ex.show()


class ForthTask(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow4):
    def __init__(self, list_nt4):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.setWindowTitle('Задание №4')
        self.n_btn_4.clicked.connect(self.check_rv4)
# !!!        
        self.label_4.setWordWrap(True)                               # +++
        self.lineEdit.setPlaceholderText('Введите слово')            # +++
        self.list_nt4 = list_nt4                                     # +++
        
        self.test_t4()

    def test_t4(self):
        global sk4, sk_rv4                 #, list_nt4

        sk4 += 1
        self.id4 = choice(self.list_nt4)
        self.list_nt4.remove(self.id4)
        if sk4 % 10 != 0:
            self.st_t4()
        else:
            self.resuit_w = Res()
            self.resuit_w.show()
            self.hide()

    def check_rv4(self):
        global sk_rv4
# ???        self.st_t4()
        self.rv = cur.execute(
            f'''select right_var_4 from 
            task_4 where id_t4 = {self.id4}''').fetchall()
        print(f'le = `{self.lineEdit.text()}`')
        print(f'db = `{self.rv[0][0]}`')
        if self.lineEdit.text() == self.rv[0][0]:
            sk_rv4 += 1

# !!!            
        self.lineEdit.clear()                                           # +++  
        self.test_t4()                                                  # +++

    def st_t4(self):
        self.task = cur.execute(
            f'''select task_4 from task_4 
            where id_t4 = {self.id4}''').fetchall()
        self.var1 = cur.execute(
            f'''select var_41 from task_4
            where id_t4 = {self.id4}''').fetchall()
        self.var2 = cur.execute(
            f'''select var_42 from task_4
                    where id_t4 = {self.id4}''').fetchall()
        self.var3 = cur.execute(
            f'''select var_43 from task_4
                    where id_t4 = {self.id4}''').fetchall()
        self.var4 = cur.execute(
            f'''select var_44 from task_4
                    where id_t4 = {self.id4}''').fetchall()
        self.var5 = cur.execute(
            f'''select var_45 from task_4
                    where id_t4 = {self.id4}''').fetchall()
        self.label_4.setText(self.task[0][0])
        self.label_41.setText(self.var1[0][0])
        self.label_42.setText(self.var2[0][0])
        self.label_43.setText(self.var3[0][0])
        self.label_44.setText(self.var4[0][0])
        self.label_45.setText(self.var5[0][0])

# !!!
# ???        self.label_4.resize(self.label_4.sizeHint())
# ???        self.lineEdit.setText('')                 # из-за этого у вас не получалось

        self.lineEdit.setFocus()                                       # +++


class Application(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle(
            'Тренажёр для подготовки к ЕГЭ по русскому языку')
        self.task_4.clicked.connect(self.forth_task)


    def forth_task(self):
        self.list_nt4 = []                                             # +++
        for i in cur.execute('select id_t4 from task_4').fetchall():   # +++
            self.list_nt4.append(*i)                                   # +++
        
        self.hide()
        self.window_4 = ForthTask(self.list_nt4)                       # +++
        self.window_4.show()


con = sqlite3.connect('project_pyqt.db')
cur = con.cursor()

sk4 = 0
sk_rv4 = 0
   

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Application()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**createDb.py**

```
from PyQt5.QtSql import QSqlDatabase, QSqlQuery


db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')
db.setDatabaseName('project_pyqt.db')
db.open()

query = QSqlQuery()
query.exec_(""" CREATE TABLE task_4
    (id_t4 INT(11) PRIMARY KEY, 
     task_4 TEXT,
     right_var_4,
     var_41 TEXT,
     var_42 TEXT,
     var_43 TEXT,
     var_44 TEXT,
     var_45 TEXT)""")
print(f'CREATE TABLE') # 
     
query.exec_("INSERT INTO task_4 (id_t4, task_4, right_var_4, var_41, var_42, var_43, var_44, var_45) " 
            "VALUES (1, 'В одном из приведённых ниже слов допущена ошибка в обозначающая ударный гласный звук. Выпишите это слово.', \
            'отзыв', 'созЫв', 'Отзыв (посла)', 'добелА', 'оптОвый', 'тубдиспансЕр')")
query.exec_("INSERT INTO task_4 (id_t4, task_4, right_var_4, var_41, var_42, var_43, var_44, var_45) " 
            "VALUES (2, 'В одном из приведённых ниже слов  это слово допущена ошибка в обозначающая ударный гласный звук. Выпишите это слово.', \
            'аэропорты', 'создАвший', 'каталОг', 'начАв', 'тОрты', 'аэропортЫ')")
query.exec_("INSERT INTO task_4 (id_t4, task_4, right_var_4, var_41, var_42, var_43, var_44, var_45) " 
            "VALUES (3, 'В одном из приведённых ниже слов допущена ошибка в постановке ударения: НЕВЕРНО выделена буква, обозначающая ударный гласный звук. Выпишите это слово.', \
            'поняла', 'обострЁнный', 'бАнты', 'начАть', 'досУг', 'пОняла')")
query.exec_("INSERT INTO task_4 (id_t4, task_4, right_var_4, var_41, var_42, var_43, var_44, var_45) " 
            "VALUES (4, 'В одном из приведённых ниже слов допущена ошибка в постановке ударения: НЕВЕРНО выделена буква, обозначающая ударный гласный звук. Выпишите это слово.', \
            'сливовый', 'укрАла', 'клАла', 'звонИт', 'прИняли', 'сливОвый (сок)')")            
query.exec_("INSERT INTO task_4 (id_t4, task_4, right_var_4, var_41, var_42, var_43, var_44, var_45) " 
            "VALUES (5, 'В одном из приведённых ниже слов допущена ошибка в постановке ударения: НЕВЕРНО выделена буква, обозначающая ударный гласный звук. Выпишите это слово.', \
            'сливовый', 'укрАла', 'клАла', 'звонИт', 'прИняли', 'сливОвый (сок)')")     
query.exec_("INSERT INTO task_4 (id_t4, task_4, right_var_4, var_41, var_42, var_43, var_44, var_45) " 
            "VALUES (6, 'В одном из приведённых ниже слов допущена ошибка в постановке ударения: НЕВЕРНО выделена буква, обозначающая ударный гласный звук. Выпишите это слово.', \
            'произведен', 'произвЕден', 'зАгодя', 'некролОг', 'облилАсь', 'началА')") 
query.exec_("INSERT INTO task_4 (id_t4, task_4, right_var_4, var_41, var_42, var_43, var_44, var_45) " 
            "VALUES (7, 'В одном из приведённых ниже слов допущена ошибка в постановке ударения: НЕВЕРНО выделена буква, обозначающая ударный гласный звук. Выпишите это слово.', \
            'включит', 'убыстрИть', 'позвонИм', 'опОшлить', 'вручИт', 'вклЮчит')")
query.exec_("INSERT INTO task_4 (id_t4, task_4, right_var_4, var_41, var_42, var_43, var_44, var_45) " 
            "VALUES (8, 'В одном из приведённых ниже слов допущена ошибка в постановке ударения: НЕВЕРНО выделена буква, обозначающая ударный гласный звук. Выпишите это слово.', \
            'цепочка', 'вручАт', 'клАла', 'цЕпочка', 'завИдно', 'чЕрпать')")
query.exec_("INSERT INTO task_4 (id_t4, task_4, right_var_4, var_41, var_42, var_43, var_44, var_45) " 
            "VALUES (9, 'В одном из приведённых ниже слов допущена ошибка в постановке ударения: НЕВЕРНО выделена буква, обозначающая ударный гласный звук. Выпишите это слово.', \
            'эксперт', 'клАла', 'взялА', 'Эксперт', 'бралА', 'квартАл')") 
query.exec_("INSERT INTO task_4 (id_t4, task_4, right_var_4, var_41, var_42, var_43, var_44, var_45) " 
            "VALUES (10, 'В одном из приведённых ниже слов допущена ошибка в постановке ударения: НЕВЕРНО выделена буква, обозначающая ударный гласный звук. Выпишите это слово.', \
            'сливовый', 'Иконопись', 'сливОвый', 'пОгнутый', 'грУшевый', 'кровоточИть')")             
db.close()
```

Comment: Да, всё заработало. Даже не задумался о совпадении названий методов. Благодарю.